# Need some advice on a websites color scheme

Tags: website-design, color, color-theory

My website is about gardening and vegetables etc. So I decided to make the background and the tabs have a green color so it looks natural and organic.

But then I realized that all my images are green because they're vegetables!

Now I can't use green as the majority of my color scheme because it blends in with most of the vegetables and it's hard to read.

Any suggestions about a new color scheme would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Greetings! It would be of great help to us all if you edited your question to include some images. Saves everyone time, and increases the chances that you will get a good answer.

Comment: This isn't answerable in this form. It's too broad of a question. Can you post samples of your site thus far?

Answer (score 1):

Some images would be good.

But there are a lot of ways to come up with good colour schemes. You could start with the most common green you have in your images, and then extract other colours that will match well by using some of the tools below. Make sure you choose something that will work as a background, so it does not steal too much from your images.

[**Colour scheme designer**](http://colorschemedesigner.com/)

[**Colourlovers: user generated colour schemes**](http://www.colourlovers.com/)

[**Adobe kuler**](https://kuler.adobe.com/)

Answer (score 0):

A little difficult without any example of your layout, the actual hues you're using and some example photos.

If your photos are dominant on the page and mostly green (will this always be the case?), I would try yellows, purples, white, black.

Depending on the layout and how your photos are handled, maybe you could stay with green and put really heavy borders (try any of the colours above) around the photos.

Sometimes sameness can be eye-catching like Leo Burnett ads for meat. Red meat on a red background. Seriously. If you're vegetarian you might not want to Google: *images leo burnett meat*

Maybe post a couple of screenshots?